# smtplib python library not sending mail on godaddy server to gmail

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm using Godaddy account with domain.But I want to send Email Godaddy domain email id to gmail email id But.But it' not working.I'm using smtplib library for sending mail.

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('HOST',PORT)
server.login('Email ID','Password')
server.sendmail('from','to','subject')
```

I'm using above code that give no error during run.and each code run successfully and login also accepted.But when i check email ID there no email found in gmail inbox and domain send email folder.
What is the mistake in my email sending procedure.

Comment: `'from'` and `'to'` does not look like  valid e-mail addresses to me. Also, did you tried to send e-mail to/from any other address? From what I can see, your e-mail message has no 'From', 'To', 'Date' fields set, which are considered mandatory by many SMTP servers.

Comment: user you server smtp, it  will maitain mail log you can check if the host has any issues.

Comment: I have tried from gmail to hotmail that work's.but on godaddy not work

Comment: Check the mail.log in your smtp sever,it will have error logged. Also 'Email Id' and 'from' varaibles should be same